# Bernoulli Variable

Tags: probability

"A Bernoulli random variable is the simplest kind of random variable. It can take on two values,1 and 0. It takes on a 1 if an experiment with probability p resulted in success and a 0 otherwise." [Source](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/070-bernoulli-binomial.pdf).

Does X is a Bernoulli random variable?
We are tossing a coin. If the result is H - We multiply 5 by 2 (success). If the result is T - We multiply 5 by 0(fail).
There are two alternatives but they are not 0 and 1.
If this is not a Bernoulli random variable - What is so special in the values 0 and 1 that make this a requirement?

Thanks

Comment: It's just a convention.

Comment: If you want the total number of successes for Bernoulli variables, you simply add them.